# Why does my LINQ generate a lot of duplicate SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

This method will generate a large number of duplicate SQL statements at runtime. Where is the problem?
ORM： EF Core 2.1

This statement generates a large number of duplicate queries when executed.

```cs
db.OpenGroup.RemoveRange(openGroups);
```

The following SQL statement is repeated dozens of times

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[OpenGroupId]
FROM [OpenGroupAdTestMap] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[OpenGroupAdTestMapId] NOT IN (
    SELECT [o3].[OpenGroupAdTestMapId]
    FROM [OpenGroupAdTestMap] AS [o3]
    WHERE [o3].[AdTestInfoId] = @__adTestInfo_Id_1
)',N'@__adTestInfo_Id_1 int',@__adTestInfo_Id_1=8
go

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT [o2].[OpenGroupId]
FROM [OpenGroupAdTestMap] AS [o2]
WHERE [o2].[AdTestInfoId] = @__adTestInfo_Id_0',N'@__adTestInfo_Id_0 int',@__adTestInfo_Id_0=8
go
```

Add the following statement to the toList.

```cs
// var deleteTg = openGroupIds.Except(adMaptgIds);
var deleteTg = openGroupIds.ToList().Except(adMaptgIds.ToList());
```

```cs
public void Run()
{
    var dbTestinfo = db.DbTestInfo.Where(o => o.Id == request).FirstOrDefault();
    if (dbTestinfo == null)
        throw new Exception($"Not found DbTestInfo by DbTestInfoId of {request}.");

    var openGroupTestMaps = db.OpenGroupTestMapp.Where(o => o.DbTestInfoId == dbTestinfo.Id);


    if (openGroupTestMaps == null && openGroupTestMaps.Count() <= 0)
    {
        db.DbTestInfo.Remove(dbTestinfo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return;
    }

    var openGroupIds = openGroupTestMaps.Select(o => o.OpenGroupId).Distinct();

    var plans = db.OpenGroupPlan.Where(o => openGroupTestMaps.Select(t => t.OpenGroupAdUnitMappingId).Contains(o.OpenGroupAdUnitMappingId)).Distinct();

    var classPlanMaps = db.OpenGroupPlanClassMapping.Where(o => plans.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(o.OpenGroupPlanId)).Distinct();

    var tagConfigs = db.TagConfig.Where(o => classPlanMaps.Select(b => b.OpenGroupPlanClassMappingId).Contains(o.OpenGroupClassMappingId)).Distinct();


    var adMaptgIds = db.OpenGroupTestMapp.Where(t => !openGroupTestMaps.Contains(t)).Select(o => o.OpenGroupId).Distinct();
    var deleteTg = openGroupIds.Except(adMaptgIds);

    var openGroups = db.OpenGroup.Where(o => deleteTg.Contains(o.Id));

    db.TagConfig.RemoveRange(tagConfigs);
    db.OpenGroupPlanClassMapping.RemoveRange(classPlanMaps);
    db.OpenGroupPlan.RemoveRange(plans);
    db.OpenGroupTestMapp.RemoveRange(openGroupTestMaps);
    db.OpenGroup.RemoveRange(openGroups);
    db.DbTestInfo.Remove(dbTestinfo);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: How can we possibly know what is going on when you haven't even told us which ORM you are using? Is it Entity Framework? If so, which version? Which queries are being duplicated? Which line of code is doing it? Remove anything in this question which is not required for us to answer.

Comment: More detailed information has been added